# What should I import for Scalaz' traverse functionalities

Tags: scala, scalaz

In every examples I read about Scalaz' traverse features, the following imports were done:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

It seems I can't use `traverseU` until I `import Scalaz._`.

How does Scalaz object inject `traverseU` to my collections? I'm completely lost in the reference doc.

What should I import if I just want the `traverse` and `traverseU` methods?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For `collection traverseU func` you'll have to import syntax for `traverseU` (implicit method for `TraverseOps`), implicit instance of `Traverse[C]` (for `collection` type `C`) and `Applicative[R]` (for `func` result type `R[X]`).

For instance:

```
import scalaz.syntax.traverse.ToTraverseOps // F[A] => TraverseOps[F, A]
import scalaz.std.list.listInstance // Traverse[List]
import scalaz.std.option.optionInstance // Applicative[Option]

List(1, 2, 3).traverseU{ Option(_) }
// Some(List(1, 2, 3))
```

In case result type of `func` is not `R[X]` with `Applicative[R]`, but some `R` with `Monoid[R]` you'll have to import `Monoid[R]` instance for implicit method `Applicative.monoidApplicative`:

```
import scalaz.std.anyVal.intInstance

List(1, 2, 3).traverseU{ identity }
// 6
```

Note that `listInstance` is also `MonadPlus[List]`, `Zip[List]`, `Unzip[List]`, etc.

So if you want to get only `Traverse[List]` for some good reason, you'll have to us it this way:

```
implicit val traverseList: scalaz.Traverse[List] = scalaz.std.list.listInstance
implicit val applicativeOption: scalaz.Applicative[Option] = scalaz.std.option.optionInstance
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you don't want to import the entire library? AFAIK, you can't import just traverse and traverseU -- they don't exist in isolation. Read up on the [Typeclass Pattern](http://bit.ly/1zzFatN) -- that should begin to answer your questions about how Scalaz does what it does. To learn more about Scalaz in general, I'd recommend the [learning Scalaz](http://eed3si9n.com/learning-scalaz/) series

Comment: I just thought importing everything from such a big library wasn't a good idea. Thanks for the links !

Comment: Importing the world increases compile time because of the extra implicits in scope.  There are also syntax methods which may clash with other libraries.

Answer (score -1):

`traverseU` is on `TraverseOps`. The conversion to that is pimped on by `TraverseSyntax`. So `import scalaz.syntax.TraverseSyntax._` should be enough.

Comment: `TraverseSyntax` is `trait`, not `object`. You can't import its members.